# Why do I need to declare props twice in vue-class-component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

When working with `vue-class-component`, I need to declare my props both in the `@Component` decorator **AND** in the class itself. It seems rather redundant and error prone.

Is this intended or am I missing something here?

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Component from 'vue-class-component'

    // Here we declare that score and counter are props
    @Component({
        props: {
            score:Number, 
            counter:Number
        }
    })

    // Now I have to declare score and counter again ?
    // Adding to the confusion is the fact that Typescript types are
    // written differently from Vue types (number vs Number)
    export default class ScoreBar extends Vue {
        score:number
        counter:number
        created(){
            console.log(`score prop is ${this.score} counter is ${this.counter}`)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey the decorator is just to make sure the variable type passed in the props is the right type ie String, Integer

Comment: But can I leave it out then? I also declare the type in the class itself so it still seems redundant. It's actually confusing because the types are written differently!

Comment: The decorator is typescript check, its just to check if the variables in your props match the specs you have set. You can have no specs or specs

Comment: Do you mean I can leave out the `@component` part entirely? Is this recommended? Isn't it weird that Vue uses two different annotations for types? Vue docs: `Number, String, Array` Typescript docs: `number, string, Array<number>`.

Comment: this is typescript, Vuejs allows you to use typescript. theres nothing weird about it. If the variable type is available for typescript, then you can use it. so yes you can use Array and Array<string> or Array<number>

Comment: I have tried to leave out `@component` but that generates an error: `Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive by initializing the property`, so it's not possible to leave that part out. I did find another tutorial that explains how to avoid having to declare props twice: https://alligator.io/vuejs/typescript-class-components/